# How would I format filtered data to new file?

Tags: bash, awk, data

Hello all I'm trying to read data from file, and check for each state and increment total transactions counts from data:

```
REDACTED
```

The end result should be printed to a new file in this format
[image: Result]

This is what I tried as a template, but I'm confused on how to increment for each state and how to exactly write in that format to the file?

```
awk -v _State=$State -v _TransactionCount=$transactionCount awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
  arr_state[$2]+=$11
END {
    print "%s\n", "Transaction Count Report"
    for (id in arr_state) {
        print "%-10s %s\n", state, arr_state[state]
    }
}' < "summary.csv" > "transaction-rpt.csv"
```

Comment: Apart from the missing $11 and the fact that you don't use the variables set by `-v`, the program looks good. You may also have to turn the state into all-caps. Is there a problem?

Comment: What about,  using 'awk -F ',' '{print $2}' summary.csv | sort | uniq -c | tr -s a-z A-Z', will convert state codes to upper case. 

One caveat -> the count comes before the state codes.

Comment: If you have multiple issues, consider asking multiple _separate_ questions.  Do not add further issues to an existing question.  I have rolled back your question's text to an earlier state.

Comment: We have redacted your example data as it looked like it contained personal information. Please update your question with fake data instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
    { arr_state[toupper($2)]+=$11 }
END {
    print "Transaction Count Report"
    for (id in arr_state) {
        printf "%-10s %d\n", id, arr_state[id]
    }
}' infile
```

Comment: How would I go about adding each transaction amount up to get $total?

Comment: @puuyo one way is using a temporary variable outside BEGIN/END, to sum up the transactions on 11th column then print within END block, you got how to do it by yourself?

Comment: @awk -v _transaction=$TRANSACTION 'BEGIN {FS=OS=","} { arr_trans[$6] += $16} END  (print "state\n" "gender\n" "transactionamount"} ' file  (format is customer_id, fname, lname, email, gender, purchase_amount, state = $12) something like that? I'm confused

Comment: Something like that? I'm confused

Comment: @puuyo wait.... what is the purpose of the use of `-v _transaction=$TRANSACTION`? in what part of your script you use that, that I cannot see. why you have changed to `arr_trans[$6] += $16`? I cannot join unsorted things honestly, can you show the main issue and your final goal? as I see youbare trying to do something with that same input but in different questions.

Comment: I'll add it below to the question so it's clearer 1 sec

Comment: good, don't forget to take note of these https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647007/how-would-i-format-filtered-data-to-new-file#comment1212639_647007  too and you talked about column#16 then you know what to do?

Comment: I added the question to the problem below EDIT if that makes my question clearer and if I'm on the right track

Comment: @puuyo use `arr_state[toupper($11) " " toupper($5)]+=$6` in the edited code you added

Answer (score 0):

Arriving late to the party, but for the sake of completing and improving a little bit on the accepted answer, I use your second example input csv file to distribute results on males and females in each state (PII in file was redacted by me):

```
$ cat infile
c77ea913-c4a2-4ff6-b615-26028b375fda,wye,nnnnnnnnn,nnnnnnnnn@ddddd.ss,0,243.54,dddddddddddddddd,8a412563-2956-4bf3-9df3-54277a9799c7,yyyy-mm-dd,ss ssss sssssss, ccccccccc,ca,90000,ddd-ddd-2825
c117f14d-1322-45a9-9f9b-63db5105fd6c,melany,nnnnnnnnn,nnnnnnnnn@ddddd.ss,0,23.26,4.dddddddddddddddd,a59201e8-9d3c-4f2b-b1fb-6914895fa5cd,yyyy-mm-dd,aa aaaaaaaaaaa aaa, ccccccccc,wv,25000,ddd-ddd-2869
3153178c-a3fb-44d3-896f-f39da69fe826,obed,nnnnnnnnnn,nnnnnnnnn@ddddddd.cc,1,477.18,dddddddddddddddd,4724a9c3-fc8a-49d3-956a-b0646364d3ef,yyyy-mm-dd,aaa aaaaa aaaaa,cccccccccccc,al,35000,ddd-ddd-8746
e4eb28e6-f960-49eb-8f5d-361df60f00c7,jerome,nnnnnnnnn,nnnnnnnnn@ddddd.cc,1,236.99,dddddddddddddddd,af393a75-6298-4c82-84e0-a778ec9956a2,yyyy-mm-dd,aa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaa,cccccccccccccccc,wv,25000,ddd-ddd-3204
b5c32ded-e769-4c52-a553-e34b548280d0,damiano,nnnnnnnnn,nnnnnnnnn@ddddd.cc,1,921.60,dddddddddddddddd,ff06abad-6787-4236-856d-74ec49df3d04,yyyy-mm-dd,aaaa aa aaaaaaaa,cccccccccccc,ok,73000,ddd-ddd-5361
```

where the 5th field's value is either "0" for females or "1" for males, following my (no-doubt questionable) gender attribution based on provided firstnames.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} 
       {assoc_arr[toupper($12)$5]+=$6} 
       END {for (id in assoc_arr) {
           printf "%-10s %-4s %8.2f\n", substr(id,1,2), substr(id,3), assoc_arr[id]
           }
       }' infile

CA         0      243.54
AL         1      477.18
WV         0       23.26
WV         1      236.99
OK         1      921.60
```

- The associate array `assoc_arr` can be made to hold any composite index values. Here, it's `toupper($12)$5`, but you could chain in any available `awk` field.
- Use "float" number formatting (as `%f`) instead of "digit" (as `%d`) in the `printf` action inside the `awk` one liner to be able to print amounts with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the count that you want to accumulate for each state (two letter combination in the second column) is the last on each line of input:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS='\t' '{ sum[$2] += $NF } END { print "State", "Transaction count"; for (i in sum) print toupper(i), sum[i] }' file.csv
State   Transaction count
OR      366.68
WV      531.13
AK      792.74
AL      477.18
TX      166.62
CA      781.65
FL      88.88
NV      858.58
MN      93.65
GA      171.06
LA      570.32
OK      921.6
```

This sets the output field separator, `OFS`, to a tab character on the command line, and also the input field delimiter, `FS`, to a comma character.  This assumes that the input is a *simple CSV file*, i.e. that it's a file containing lines with comma-delimited fields, where no field contains embedded commas or newline characters.

The associative array `sum` uses the second field as its key, and for each line, the sum is incremented using the last field on the line.

At the end, a simple header is printed, and the collected data in the `sum` array is outputted.

As a stand-alone `awk` program, the code would be written as

```c
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
    OFS = "\t"
}

{
    sum[$2] += $NF
} 

END {
    print "State", "Transaction count"

    for (i in sum)
        print toupper(i), sum[i]
}
```

This would be used as

```
$ awk -f script.awk file.csv
```

Would you want the sum rounded to the nearest integer, print `int(sum[i]+0.5)` instead of just `sum[i]`.