# Compute and print summary with cumulative amounts by state and gender from csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk

How would I go about something like this?

```
Purchase Summary Report
State Gender Purchase Amount
TX F 33734.33
CA F 23911.61
TX M 23043.64
FL M 18846.49
```

I need to sum the total transactions (2 decimal places) and and sort it by Male and Female for each state?

the data

```
customer_id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,purchase_amount,credit_card,transaction_id,transaction_date,street,city,state,zip,phone
```

example

```
$ cat infile
c77ea913-c4a2-4ff6-b615-26028b375fda,wye,nnnnnnnnn,nnnnnnnnn@ddddd.ss,F,23911.61,dddddddddddddddd,8a412563-2956-4bf3-9df3-54277a9799c7,yyyy-mm-dd,ss ssss sssssss, ccccccccc,ca,93000,ddd-ddd-2825
c117f14d-1322-45a9-9f9b-63db5105fd6c,melany,nnnnnnnnn,nnnnnnnnn@ddddd.ss,F,33100.03,dddddddddddddddd,a59201e8-9d3c-4f2b-b1fb-6914895fa5cd,yyyy-mm-dd,aa aaaaaaaaaaa aaa, ccccccccc,tx,73000,ddd-ddd-2869
3153178c-a3fb-44d3-896f-f39da69fe826,nancy,nnnnnnnnnn,nnnnnnnnn@ddddddd.cc,F,634.30,dddddddddddddddd,4724a9c3-fc8a-49d3-956a-b0646364d3ef,yyyy-mm-dd,aaa aaaaa aaaaa,cccccccccccc,tx,73000,ddd-ddd-8746
e4eb28e6-f960-49eb-8f5d-361df60f00c7,jerome,nnnnnnnnn,nnnnnnnnn@ddddd.cc,M,23043.64,dddddddddddddddd,af393a75-6298-4c82-84e0-a778ec9956a2,yyyy-mm-dd,aa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaa,cccccccccccccccc,tx,73000,ddd-ddd-3204
b5c32ded-e769-4c52-a553-e34b548280d0,damiano,nnnnnnnnn,nnnnnnnnn@ddddd.cc,M,18846.49,dddddddddddddddd,ff06abad-6787-4236-856d-74ec49df3d04,yyyy-mm-dd,aaaa aa aaaaaaaa,cccccccccccc,fl,32000,ddd-ddd-5361
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
    { arr_state[toupper($12) toupper($5)]+=$6 }
END {
    print "Transaction Count Report"
    for (id in arr_state) {
        printf "%-10s %d\n", id, arr_state[id]
    }
}' infile
```

my results are

```
Transaction Count Report
State Gender Amount
SCM        2322
MOF        9015
TNM        6671
OR0        3470
WI0        3295
MS0        2640
AZ0        7747
NM0        1090
MD0        2943
AK0        2541
```

Comment: your gender all are 0 in given sample input, instead of M/F as you want based on your expected output; or do you want mapping 0/1 to M/F or F/M?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized where I went wrong how would I tab space between STATE and gender?

Comment: already pointed here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647007/how-would-i-format-filtered-data-to-new-file/647014#comment1212699_647014, replace space there with any character or string youbwant, for tab do `arr_state[toupper($12) "\t" toupper($5)]+=$6`

Comment: I tried "printf "%.2f %d\n", id, arr_state[id]" is there a way to specify ONLY transaction amount as a float?

Comment: We have redacted your example data as it looked like it contained personal information.  Please update your question with fake data instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";print "State Gender Purchase Amount"} 
       {assoc_arr[toupper($12)$5]+=$6} 
       END {for (id in assoc_arr) {
           printf "%-8s %-8s %8.2f\n", substr(id,1,2), substr(id,3), assoc_arr[id]
           }
       }' infile

State Gender Purchase Amount
TX       M        23043.64
CA       F        23911.61
TX       F        33734.33
FL       M        18846.49
```

- The associate array assoc_arr can be made to hold any composite index values. Here, it's `toupper($12)$5`, but you could chain in any available `awk` record's field.
- Use "float" number formatting (as `%f`) in the printf action inside the awk one liner to be able to print amounts with decimals.